# YII - bootstrap css overrides custom css rules

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am working on a YII based Web application whose backend is based on bootstrap css.
Now on front end YII's bootstrap is overriding custom css rules.

like one example is

tag. following is bootstrap generated css rules

```
  p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 9px;
  }
```

We do not have any margin for

but due to `margin: 0 0 9px;` in bootstrap is effecting
 whole page CSS

Issue is that how to override bootstrap rules while using custom CSS. 
I tired by adding in Action  `$this->layout='//layouts/main';`

but it seems it is picking from Assets folder. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why not override the bootstrap css?

Comment: @Renier thanks. but how??? adding a new rule for a tag is not solution

Comment: So you're not looking for something like: `p{margin: 0 0 0px;}`? this would override the bootstrap css.

Comment: i tried that already. With margin 0 all p tags space is removed while if i disable above rule in firebug every thing becomes ok.

Comment: Why then not change it at the source? You can do that if you are not going to use the `Bootstrap` style for `p` tags throughout your project. That is the only other solution I can think of... unless you play around with the styles a little, i.e. change the values of every thing in the rule for the `p` tag.

Comment: Sorry i could not get. are you referring to inline style for tag or directly in bootstrap? Bootstrap is used in backend panel of site and is in assets folder where it is picking automatically.

Comment: How is the backend based on a front-end CSS framework?

Comment: I mean there are two layout files for the site. one for backend one for front end. backend layout file is based on bootstrap. it loads bootstrap from assets manager. And the front end do not load bootstrap but yii automatically loads it.

Comment: In your header, in which order do you load boostrap's css and your own css?

Comment: I do not load bootstrap in front end layout file.

Answer (score 0):

One option - to realize backend as a separate module with its own layout or theme (you can add it to the init section of the Module class by setting: `Yii::app()->theme = 'themename';` ). For the frontend use a different layout or theme which will not connect bootstrap style files.

Another option - use a different layout for the frontend controller (`public $layout='frontendLayout';` in a Controller class) which also should not be connected bootstrap stylesheets.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Im exactly doing as your second option.
public $layout='//layouts/main'; for fron end and public $layout='//layouts/backend'; for backend. no connection to bootstrap in frontend layout file. it refers to asset manager when seen in firebug

Comment: If you use an Yii bootstrap extension, then make sure that the layout does not have this line: `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();`

Comment: thanks. In layout i do not have this line but in config there are in 'preload'=>array('bootstrap') and in components.

Comment: try connect extension only for module: add in config `'modules'=>array(
      'backendModule'=>array(
         'preload'=>array('bootstrap'),
         'components'=>array(
            'bootstrap'=>array(
                'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
             ),
         ),
      ),
   ),` ofcourse if you use module!

Answer (score 0):

sometimes convenient to raise the priority of your style property by `!important`. Example

```
p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 9px;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I know this but <p> is one example there are alot of tags whose css is overwritten by bootstrap. so need to change for all.